# Handle lots of session files with apache2 and php

Tags: php, session, apache2

I'm currently running into a huge problem regarding performance more precisely: Load generated through lots of I/O on an flat sessions folder with lots of files (+100.000).

The sessionfiles/htdocs folder is located on an managed storage - two seperate servers (behind a loadbalancer) are using these files (apache2) through an nsf-mount and are accessing the same sessions folder (to keep it persistent) at once.

Unfortunately the project is highly frequented and is generating a lot of sessionfiles. Even with ans max_lifetime of 2 hours we're generating +100.000 sessionfiles which is way to much for IO Nodes.

Is there a possibility to split - dynamically - these sessions into subfolders? e.g. all sessionfiles with sess_1* into /tmp/sessions/1, sess_2 into /tmp/sessions/2 and so on? With this approach the storage/IO Nodes only had to handle ~10.000 each folder which should speed up the garbage collection and should guard against IO Load.

I found this excerpt from the PHP (session.save_path) doc:

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

> There is an optional N argument to this directive that determines the
>   number of directory levels your session files will be spread around
>   in. For example, setting to '5;/tmp' may end up creating a session
>   file and location like
>   /tmp/4/b/1/e/3/sess_4b1e384ad74619bd212e236e52a5a174If . In order to
>   use N you must create all of these directories before use. A small
>   shell script exists in ext/session to do this, it's called
>   mod_files.sh, with a Windows version called mod_files.bat. Also note
>   that if N is used and greater than 0 then automatic garbage collection
>   will not be performed, see a copy of php.ini for further information.
>   Also, if you use N, be sure to surround session.save_path in "quotes"
>   because the separator (;) is also used for comments in php.ini.

Does anyone have been implementing this before in php and could provide me with some sample php code to handle sessionfiles in subfolders using this mod_files.sh?

unfortunatly its pretty poorly documented ...

Comment: Don't keep sessions in files. Use Redis or Memcached.

Comment: The documentation you quoted quite clearly solves the problem: "setting to '5;/tmp'". But you may want to consider using something other than files for sessions.

Comment: is it necessarily to store sessions on files? cuz you can save just put them into memcache. For me it works for website with more then million sessions.

Comment: OZ_ and pomaxa: Thanks for the reply!
sessionfiles is the (for me) easiest way to handle sessions/persistant across mutliple (in this case two) servers ... is it possbile to use memcache and share this cache to all (apache-)servers through nfs mount? or only via database?


We've got a seperate sql server with a quite high (but "ok") load - don't really want to push the db-server to its limits and run into new problems.

Comment: Don't use DB for sessions - very soon auto-increment fields will be overflowed. Why do you need some "nfs mount" if you will use Redis or Memcached? Just use separate VPS for this (in local network for your servers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the solution is easier than it might appear at first. Somehow I thought the PHP has to handle and manage the apache requests to the sessions directory tree. However the Apache does it on its own once the session:save_path has been changed.

**1.)** call this (modified) script ( http://snipplr.com/view/27710/modfilessh-php/ ) once via ssh:

*sh path/to/script/mod_files.sh path/to/sessions depth* (in my case: "mod_files.sh /tmp/sessions 1"

**2.)** doublecheck chown rights of new sessions directory tree

**3.)** change "session.save_path" to "1;/tmp/sessions"

Thanks for your help nevertheless!

Comment: And don't forget to disable the internal garbage collection and add an custom one (e.g. with an scheuduled cronjob) because the automatic garbage collection will not be performed if you're using a directory tree.